# Passing an Object from an Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` which uses a `Fragment`. I simply want to pass an object from this `Activity` to the `Fragment`.

How could I do it?
All the tutorials I've seen so far where retrieving data from resources.

EDIT :

Let's be a bit more precise:

My Activity has a `ListView` on the left part. When you click on it, the idea is to load a `Fragment` on the right part.

When I enter this `Activity`, an Object `Category` is given through the `Intent`. This Object contains a List of other Objects `Questions` (which contains a List of String). These `Questions` objects are displayed on the ListView.
When I click on one item from the `ListView`, I want to display the List of `String` into the `Fragment` (into a `ListView`).

To do that, I call the `setContentView()` from my `Activity` with a layout. In this layout is defined the `Fragment` with the correct class to call.
When I call this `setContentView()`, the `onCreateView()` of my `Fragment` is called but at this time, the `getArguments()` returns null.

How could I manage to have it filled before the call of `onCreateView()` ?
(tell me if I'm not clear enough)

Thanks

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Create a static method in the `Fragment` and then get it using `getArguments()`.

Example:

```
public class CommentsFragment extends Fragment {
  private static final String DESCRIBABLE_KEY = "describable_key";
  private Describable mDescribable;

  public static CommentsFragment newInstance(Describable describable) {
    CommentsFragment fragment = new CommentsFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(DESCRIBABLE_KEY, describable);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mDescribable = (Describable) getArguments().getSerializable(
        DESCRIBABLE_KEY);

    // The rest of your code
}
```

You can afterwards call it from the `Activity` doing something like:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = CommentsFragment.newInstance(mDescribable);
ft.replace(R.id.comments_fragment, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Hello Macarse, when your method newInstance is called ?

Comment: Are you sure you meant `Describable` instead of `Serializable`?

Comment: yup it's `Describable`; he's casting the serialised data back to its class

Comment: What is I want to pass some object which is not Serializable?

Comment: putParcelable is the best practice way

Comment: I would love to know why not simply set `fragment.mDescribable = describable;` in newInstance? It works, but is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: @RahulThakur You are missing the point of the `m` prefix here. As the Java community strongly encourages the concept of data encapsulation, it should be noted that private fields need not be accessible outside. The reason why, it is passed as a parameter from the singleton method is because that field is mandatory in that context, and thus reducing the potential risk that you will forgot to assign its value.

Comment: Best answer, but you forget to say that `Object` need to implements `Serializable` to work (in the case, the object `Describable`).

Comment: @GabrielStafoca yeah, I don't know about `Describable`, but many other objects will require to put them in class that implements `Serializable` and then we can send this class using `bundle.putSerializable`. And author of this answer really didn't mention about it. So it's not a good answer...

Comment: @RahulThakur Because you can't set an instance variable (mDescribable) from a static context.

Comment: It would seem `Parcelable` gives as much as a 10x speed boost -- http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: What if I need to pass some complex object to Fragment from Activity after some period of time, when Fragment is already visible? Can I just add public method like this: public void setCustomDataToFragment(MyCustomObject obj)?

Comment: @RahulThakur Android system calls the no argument constructor when re-creating the fragment for eg. on activity configuration changed. Ideally fragment parameters should be passed through arguments.

Answer (score 15):

In your activity class:

```
public class BasicActivity extends Activity {

private ComplexObject co;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

    co=new ComplexObject();
    getIntent().putExtra("complexObject", co);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, f1).commit();

}
```

Note: Your object should implement Serializable interface

Then in your fragment :

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

ComplexObject co;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();

    co = (ComplexObject) i.getSerializableExtra("complexObject");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_page, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DENEME);
    textView.setText(co.getName());

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: This wokerd perfeclty for me! thanks @Tugce Saritas

Answer (score 13):

You should create a method within your fragment that accepts the type of object you wish to pass into it. In this case i named it "setObject" (creative huh? :) ) That method can then perform whatever action you need with that object.

```
MyFragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, detailsFragment)
                    .commit();
        } else {
           fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    android.R.id.content);
        }


        fragment.setObject(yourObject); //create a method like this in your class "MyFragment"
}
```

Note that i'm using the support library and calls to getSupportFragmentManager() might be just getFragmentManager() for you depending on what you're working with

Comment: Just be careful when using this method on a fragment that can outlive your hosting view (retainInstance true).

Comment: This won't work. When your app dies in the background, and the user brings it back to the foreground, `setObject` won't necessarily be called.

Comment: @MartinKonecny in that case the onCreate method will be called again (because the activity will be recreated) and therefore also setObject would be called. If it is not the case, please explain your comment. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work in case of view pager fragments. since the object is not retained on the transition.

Answer (score 7):

Get reference from the following example.

**1.  In fragment**:
Create a reference variable for the class whose object you want in the fragment. Simply create a setter method for the reference variable and call the setter before replacing fragment from the activity.

```
 MyEmployee myEmp;
 public void setEmployee(MyEmployee myEmp)
 {
     this.myEmp = myEmp;
 }
```

**2.  In activity**:

```
   //we need to pass object myEmp to fragment myFragment

    MyEmployee myEmp = new MyEmployee();

    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    myFragment.setEmployee(myEmp);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_layout, myFragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 5):

Passing arguments by bundle is restricted to some data types. But you can transfer any data to your fragment this way:

In your fragment create a public method like this

```
public void passData(Context context, List<LexItem> list, int pos) {
    mContext = context;
    mLexItemList = list;
    mIndex = pos;
}
```

and in your activity call passData() with all your needed data types after instantiating the fragment

```
        WebViewFragment myFragment = new WebViewFragment();
        myFragment.passData(getApplicationContext(), mLexItemList, index);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.my_fragment_container, myFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

Remark: My fragment extends "android.support.v4.app.Fragment", therefore I have to use "getSupportFragmentManager()". Of course, this principle will work also with a fragment class extending "Fragment", but then you have to use "getFragmentManager()".

Answer (score 1):

To pass an object to a fragment, do the following:

First store the objects in Bundle, don't forget to put implements serializable in class.

```
            CategoryRowFragment fragment = new CategoryRowFragment();

            // pass arguments to fragment
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            // event list we want to populate
            bundle.putSerializable("eventsList", eventsList);

            // the description of the row
            bundle.putSerializable("categoryRow", categoryRow);

            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then retrieve bundles in Fragment

```js
       // events that will be populated in this row
        mEventsList = (ArrayList<Event>)getArguments().getSerializable("eventsList");

        // description of events to be populated in this row
        mCategoryRow = (CategoryRow)getArguments().getSerializable("categoryRow");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data should survive throughout the application lifecycle and shared among multiple fragments or activities, a `Model` class might come into consideration, which has got less serialization overhead.

Check this [design example](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

Answer (score -1):

This one worked for me:

In Activity:

```
User user;
public User getUser(){ return this.user;}
```

In Fragment's onCreateView method:

```
User user = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getUser();
```

Replace the `MainActivity` with your Activity Name.