# Passing an JSON Object from an Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity which uses a Fragment. I simply want to pass an JSONObject from this Activity to the Fragment.How could I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an Object from an Activity to a Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931993/passing-an-object-from-an-activity-to-a-fragment)

Comment: I think you can convert the JSON object into toString pass from activity to fragment and make the json object from string in your fragment

Answer (score 1):

Do this:
lets say this is the jsonObject: **JSONObject obj=...;**
to add your fragment, do this:

```
<Your_fragment_name> myFrag=<Your_fragment_name>();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key",obj.toString());
    Frag frag=new Frag();
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(<your_container_id>,myFrag).commit();
```

then in your fragment's **onCreateView()** add this to get the json back

```
 Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    String jsonString=bundle.getString("key");
    JSONObject obj;
    try {
        obj=new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in your activity, then you can get that from fragment. Try to convert JSON to string using `toString()`, then get that string from fragment.

Comment: I didn't use Android SDK from a long time but I believe that you can add Object to the intent, just put the JSONObject into the intent et recover it on the other side (with some casting)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the JSON object public in the activity and then you can access it in your fragment by using

```
getActivity().jsonObject
```