# How to pass HashMap<String, Object> through bundle arguments in fragment?

Tags: android, object, serialization, hashmap

I am trying to pass HashMap through arguments .But I am getting empty hashmap while getting it through getSeralizable method(Hashmap that I am putting is not empty & having a size of 11). The following is my code snippet.

```
public static FirstPageFragment newInstance(boolean is_pending, HashMap<String, Object> result_map) {
    FirstPageFragment fragment = new FirstPageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean(ARG_PARAM1, is_pending);
    args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM2, result_map);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        Bundle b=getArguments();
        isPending = b.getBoolean(ARG_PARAM1);
        mResultMap = (HashMap<String, Object>)b.getSerializable(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}
```

Can we do like this? If it can't be done like this, is there any alternate way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("YourHashMap",hashMap);
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

and in the other Activity

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle != null) {
   hashMap = bundle.getSerializable("YourHashMap");
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html

<sub>**HashMap**</sub> ___

> extends AbstractMap **implements** Map, Cloneable,
>   **Serializable**

Comment: It's working in activity. But is it possible to set the bundle as arguments in fragment?

Comment: @Anu  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931993/passing-an-object-from-an-activity-to-a-fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this as `HashMap` implementation is serializable

Answer (score 0):

Use `putExtra(String key, Serializable obj)` to insert the `HashMap` and on the other Activity use `getIntent().getSerializableExtra(String key)`, You will need to Cast the return value as a `HashMap` though.